# How to generate a horizontal histogram with words?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, symbolic, histograms, symbols

I have a dataset of the type:

```
data={{826777, "National Natural Science Foundation of China"}, {315253, 
  "National Science Foundation"}, {159274, 
  "U.S. Department of Energy"}, {133993, 
  "Japan Society for the Promotion of Science"}, {119710, 
  "Fundamental Research Funds for the Central Universities"}, {111064,
   "National Key Research and Development Program of China"}, {108416,
   "National Institutes of Health"}, {103238, 
  "Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft"}, {85648, 
  "National Research Foundation of Korea"}, {80981, 
  "Seventh Framework Programme"}, {79600, 
  "Engineering and Physical Sciences Research Council"}, {78383, 
  "European Commission"}, {74952, 
  "Natural Sciences and Engineering Research Council of Canada"}, \
{73368, "Horizon 2020 Framework Programme"}, {67414, 
  "Conselho Nacional de Desenvolvimento Científico e Tecnológico"}, \
{57697, "Russian Foundation for Basic Research"}, {56817, 
  "China Postdoctoral Science Foundation"}, {54863, 
  "Ministry of Education, Culture, Sports, Science and Technology"}, \
{53150, "Chinese Academy of Sciences"}, {52416, 
  "European Regional Development Fund"}, {42511, 
  "Office of Science"}, {36152, "European Research Council"}, {34774, 
  "Coordenação de Aperfeiçoamento de Pessoal de Nível Superior"}, \
{33632, "National Basic Research Program of China (973 Program)"}, \
{30444, "Ministry of Science, ICT and Future Planning"}, {28627, 
  "Basic Energy Sciences"}, {27370, 
  "Directorate for Mathematical and Physical Sciences"}, {26223, 
  "Natural Science Foundation of Jiangsu Province"}, {25302, 
  "National Institute of General Medical Sciences"}, {24688, 
  "China Scholarship Council"}, {24341, 
  "Ministry of Education of the People's Republic of China"}, {21671, 
  "Fundação de Amparo à Pesquisa do Estado de São Paulo"}, {18971, 
  "National Aeronautics and Space Administration"}, {17687, 
  "Priority Academic Program Development of Jiangsu Higher Education \
Institutions"}, {17626, "Ministry of Education"}, {17503, 
  "Ministerio de Economía y Competitividad"}, {16194, 
  "Ministry of Science and Technology of the People's Republic of \
China"}};
```

I would like to generate a histogram of word and number as shown in Figure bellow:

[image]

I tried using the following code:

```
Histogram[Mdata2, Automatic, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

But the output was

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you don't need a `Histogram`, you need [`BarChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html). Secondly, you need to massage the data slightly so each data point is associated with its label.

This is a possible approach:

```
BarChart[
  Labeled[#1, #2] & @@@ Sort@data,
  BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Full
]
```

[image: desired bar chart]

Answer (score 8):

Another way that includes your chart colour and gridlines

```
BarChart[
 Sort[data][[All, 1]],
 ChartLabels -> Sort[data][[All, 2]],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartStyle -> LightBlue,
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None}
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To get even closer with the colours requested on the original example we can get the correct blue with `DominantColors`

[image: DominantColorsCode]

And we can also use `EdgeForm->None` to remove the borders on the bar and use `TicksStyle -> Opacity[0]` to delete the ticks near the labels and `LabelStyle -> Opacity[1]` to keep the text.

[image: TicksAndBorder]

```
BarChart[
 Sort[data][[All, 1]],
 ChartLabels -> Sort[data][[All, 2]],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartStyle -> {chartColorsOnBar, {EdgeForm -> 
     None}},(*correct shade of blue and no edges*)
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 TicksStyle -> Opacity[0],(*remove tick marks near labels*)
 LabelStyle -> Opacity[1](*remove tick marks near labels*)
 ]
```

> [image: finalchart]